# Rails with Angular 2 ( for stand-alone web apps)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, angular

I have been learning rails for over 4-5 months.I would say i am intermediate(ish) on rails.Past week, i got interested in angular2.Since it is written in TypeScript, it was little diffrent for me.Can rails do what angular2 can do? I mean single page app things? Should i invest the time to learn it, or just move along with rails? And if i leave angular2, can i still make single page rails apps?
I know this might not be the place for this question, but i haven't got an answer from quora for past 4 days.This question really bothering me mentally and psyhically. It is bothering my mind, and preventing me to learn anything at all.Please help.

Comment: Main question.Should i try to learn angular2 also, or just move on with rails4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is a client side app only.
Rails is a server side app.

Rails would be the more complete package as it can accomplish everything Angular can in it's own way.

There's no definitive answer for this but it really just comes down to what your project's requirements are.

Angular is great for font-end single page client side apps. 
Rails is great for server side, database ORM etc.

With that being said there's nothing stopping you from using both in one app. It's a little too broad to cover here.

Comment: The truth is, i dont get the point of combining rails with angular2.What is the plus side of doing so? Is it just the single page thing? I think it can be done with ajax right? I feel like i am WASTİNG TİME trying to learn both at the same time.

Comment: They both huge frameworks.And trying to learn both, i feel like i am not efficient in both of them.I feel like i am doing something wrong.

Comment: You can accomplish nearly everything Angular does and more with Rails. If you're unsure right now - I recommend sticking to Rails since you have the most experience in that.

Comment: Thing is, i am lost on doubts.Didn't do anything past 2 days.I am afraid to make the wrong decision.I can use ajax or angular 1 on rails instead of angular 2 right?Would it be any diffrent using angular2 or 1 ? (besides performance)

Comment: Without going too far off topic I'll refer you to this blog post which goes into detail that you require.
https://dzone.com/articles/typed-front-end-with-angular-2

Comment: Thank you so much .I will check out other sites too.Appreciated the help alot. ^^

Comment: Furthermore - even though this comment is opinionated: I recommend sticking with Rails and becoming a master in it. There are more jobs requiring Rails developers than there are for Angular. It also depends on what you love to do. Frontend = Angular. Backend logic and databases = Rails.

Comment: Thanks for caring.Still one question mark left.I can use ajax for single page apps right?